# Detecting the outlier from rows by certain column in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have datasets which measure voltage values in certain column.
I'm looking for elegant way to extract the rows that is deviated from mean value. There are couple of group in "volt_id" and I'd like to have each group create their own mean/std and use them to decide which rows are deviated from each group. 
for example, I have original dataset as below.

```
      time     volt_id     value
 0    14         A         300.00
 1    15         A         310.00
 2    15         B         200.00
 3    16         B         210.00
 4    17         B         300.00
 5    14         C         100.00
 6    16         C         110.00
 7    20         C         200.00
```

After the algorithm running, I'd only keep row 4 and 7 which is highly deviated from their groups as below.

```
      time     volt_id     value
 4    17         B         300.00
 7    20         C         200.00
```

I could do this if there is only single group but my codes would be messy and lengthy if do this for multiple groups. I'd appreciate if there's simpler way to do this.

thanks,

Comment: Define "highly deviated"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compute and filter on the [zscore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) on each `group` using `groupby`.

Assuming you want only those rows which are 1 or more standard deviations away from mean,

```
g = df.groupby('volt_id').value
v = (df.value - g.transform('mean')) / g.transform('std')

df[v.abs().ge(1)]

   time volt_id  value
4    17       B  300.0
7    20       C  200.0
```

Comment: thanks! it is elegant and simple! I wouldn't think about this way.

Comment: BTW, what does ge function do here? is it setting True for values greater than 1 similar to what MaxU below implemented in different way?

Comment: @JoohunLee "greater than or equal to". MaxU has implemented "greater than".

Comment: thanks for your answer!  I also figured out right after I posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @COLDSPEED's solution:

```
In [179]: from scipy.stats import zscore

In [180]: df.loc[df.groupby('volt_id')['value'].transform(zscore) > 1]
Out[180]:
   time volt_id  value
4    17       B  300.0
7    20       C  200.0
```

Comment: This is also very helpful and easier to understand. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be using outliers:
http://www.mathwords.com/o/outlier.htm

You would need to define your inner quartile range and first and third quartiles. You could then filter your data onsimple comparison.

Quartiles are not the only way to determine outliers howevet. Heres a discussion comparing standard deviation and quartiles for locating outliers: 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175999/determine-outliers-using-iqr-or-standard-deviation

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.